# illegal XML character backbone.js template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, templates, backbone.js

I've got a rails project in which I read in a template file and in the javascript console I get the following error:

```
illegal XML character
appointment_show.js?body=1()appoin...?body=1 (line 2)
[Break On This Error] this.JST["appointments/show"] = <%= topic %>;
```

Here is my current Backbone view I'm playing around with:

```
window.AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST["appointments/show"],

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Here is my app/assets/templates/appointments/show.jst file

```
<%= topic %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was rename my app/assets/templates/appointments/show.jst to show.jst.ejs